# How to display the dashboard with data from Facebook Analytics

Tags: javascript, reporting, analytics, facebook-analytics

Is there a method to access report data in Facebook Analytics using javascript?

I need to display a dashboard with that data on a site I'm developing

[like this api from google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can leverage the App Insights API to pull event data with some breakdowns: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights/.